# In the Universal Coefficient Theorem, how does the cohomology generator relate to the homology generators?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Consider homology and cohomology of some space $X$ where the homology groups are finitely generated. Consider $tor(H^i(X))$, the torsion part of $H^i(X)$.

How do the generators of $tor(H^i(X))$ relate to the generators of $H_{i-1}(X)$ in the Universal Coefficient Theorem?

Is there a way of espressing the generators of $tor(H^i(X))$ in terms of the generators of $H_{i-1}(X)$, maybe an expression of the generators on the chain and cochain level?

Comment: Maybe I should edit my question. If there is no torsion, then the cohomology generators are considered dual to the homology generators. Can a similar statement be said about the torsion cohomology generators? Since torsion moves up a degree when going from homology to cohomology, there is not really a notion of duality since the torsion elements come from Ext, but what is the relation? What are the choices of generators for cohomology?

Comment: From what I understand, they are not exactly dual, in the usual sense of duality.

Comment: Yes, they are the same as groups, but I am interested in the generators, see my edits to my question. Why should one not care? It would be interesting to know, especially how something algebraic can relate to the topological space. I care because in fact, knowing the relation would ease a computation I am doing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking now. I apologize. Anyway, my comments appear to be worthless, so unless you object, I'll delete the whole lot to avoid clutter.

Comment: Sure, thanks for commenting, it helped me clarify my question.